# How to Resume Music After ScreenUnlock in android

Tags: android, android-listview

Hi in my application i need to  stop music when i click power button,homebutton,back button so i tried using below code its working fn for both home and back button..but i am facing prblem in power button..using below  code i can able stop sound when i press home button and i problem is again i press power button that time sound is playing but i need to resume sound after unlock,so i took another falg Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT this falg is calling when i unlock the screen but before this flag calling only onresume() is firing so,i am not able to write when screen unlock that time sound should play like that.. any one suggest me thank you.

```
   public class MainMenu extends Activity{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
     screenHeight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
     screenWidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;


     IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
     filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
     filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT);

     BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new ScreenReceiver();
     registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter); //register
    setContentView(R.layout.mainmenu);

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();

    Log.i("","-----------onPause----------");

    if (mediaPlayer1 != null) {

        if (mediaPlayer1.isPlaying()) {

            mediaPlayer1.pause();
            Globalclass.length=mediaPlayer1.getCurrentPosition();

        }

           }

    if(Globalclass.power==1)
    {
         Globalclass.hmecount=1;
         Globalclass.backcount=0;
        if (mediaPlayer1 != null) {

            if (mediaPlayer1.isPlaying()) {

                mediaPlayer1.pause();
                Globalclass.lengthscreen=mediaPlayer1.getCurrentPosition();

            }
        }
    }

   }
   protected void onResume() {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     super.onResume();

      if(Globalclass.hmecount==1)
      {
     mediaPlayer1 = MediaPlayer.create(MainMenu.this, R.raw.bgmusic);
        mediaPlayer1.seekTo(Globalclass.length);
          mediaPlayer1.setLooping(true);
        mediaPlayer1.start();

}
else if(Globalclass.backcount==1)

{
     mediaPlayer1 = MediaPlayer.create(MainMenu.this, R.raw.bgmusic);
      mediaPlayer1.setLooping(true);
        mediaPlayer1.start();
}
else if(Globalclass.power==2)
{

    mediaPlayer1 = MediaPlayer.create(MainMenu.this, R.raw.bgmusic);
    mediaPlayer1.seekTo(Globalclass.lengthscreen);
     mediaPlayer1.setLooping(true);
    mediaPlayer1.start();

}
else if(Globalclass.power==1)
{

}
     else 
{
     mediaPlayer1 = MediaPlayer.create(MainMenu.this, R.raw.bgmusic);
      mediaPlayer1.setLooping(true);
        mediaPlayer1.start();
}

Log.i("","----------length1------------"+Globalclass.length);
Log.i("","----------hmecount------------"+Globalclass.hmecount);
Log.i("","----------backcount------------"+Globalclass.backcount);
Log.i("","----------power------------"+Globalclass.power);

      }



@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i("-----------onDestroy----------","");


}



@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)) {
     Globalclass.hmecount=1;
     Globalclass.backcount=0;
  System.out.println("KEYCODE_HOME");

   Intent intent = new Intent(
         Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
          intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
         intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
         startActivity(intent);
        return true;
}
if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
System.out.println("KEYCODE_BACK");
 Globalclass.backcount=1;
 Globalclass.hmecount=0;
 Intent intent = new Intent(
         Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
       intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
       intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
         startActivity(intent);
        finish();
       return true;
}


return false;
}
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
super.onAttachedToWindow();
this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD); 
}
   }

public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
   @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
        // DO WHATEVER YOU NEED TO DO HERE
         Globalclass.power=1;

      } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
        // AND DO WHATEVER YOU NEED TO DO HERE
    }
    else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)){

         Globalclass.power=2;
    }
}
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this function in your activity:

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if(hasFocus) 
       //play music
    else
      //pause music
}
```

This api is always caled in activity when your app gain or looses focus. I think it is best place in your case to handle your scenario

Comment: hi thanks..its working fine..but when screen visable top one bar is showing i dnt want that bar

Answer (score 0):

In your Mainfest file put those files to allow your app to receive a broadcast message if any action happened to the unlock screen

```
<receiver android:name=".ScreenReceiver">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF"/>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON"/>
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Then on the Broadcast receive do this:

```
public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON))
     {
        Intent intent = new Intent();  
        intent.setClass(context, ScreenLockActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);          
     }
     else if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF))
     {
      //Perform a specific action if you need
     }


}
}
```

I hope this helps